# How to retrieve any existing Bible verse including accentuated bible books from any content into an array

Tags: php

I have successfully been able to retrieve any bible verse that is place between brackets like (John 3:16) but I have been looking for a way in php to retrieve any bible verse in any string into an array per bible verse. None of the search result I have found on stack overflow matches what I want. Let's say I have a content like this :

> Here is a content where **Genèse 11:10-12, 15-17, 19-20**. And other
> verses scattered anywhere in the content like **2 Chronicles 12:10-12,
> 15-17, 19-20** and **3 John 3** and soemthing else.

How can I retrieve any of these Bible verses into an array so that this array will contain the following e respective of the Gen**è**se accent **è** ?

```
array("Genèse 11:10-12, 15-17, 19-20", "2 Chronicles 12:10-12, 15-17, 19-20", "3 John 3");
```

How to retrieve any existing Bible verse including accentuated bible books from any content into an array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `preg_match_all` with an appropriate regex pattern:

```php
$input = "Here is a content where Genèse 11:10-12, 15-17, 19-20. And other verses scattered anywhere in the content like 2 Chronicles 12:10-12, 15-17, 19-20 and 3 John 3 and soemthing else.";
preg_match_all("/(?:\d+ )?[A-Z]\S+ \d+(?::\d+(?:-\d+)?(?:, \d+(?:-\d+)?)*)?/", $input, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Genèse 11:10-12, 15-17, 19-20
    [1] => 2 Chronicles 12:10-12, 15-17, 19-20
    [2] => 3 John 3
)
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

- `(?:\d+ )?` match optional book number (e.g. 1 Kings, 2 Chronicles)
- `[A-Z]\S+` match book name (includes possible accented characters)
- space
- `\d+` match chapter number
- `(?:` start optional group
- `:` match colon
- `\d+(?:-\d+)?` match verse number followed by optional range
- `(?:, \d+(?:-\d+)?)*` match zero or more verse ranges
- `)?` close optional group

Comment: This is awesome. Please before I validate this as an anwer can you add an option for bible version added at the end like `2 Chronicles 12:10-12, 15-17, 19-20 Amp`  `Genèse 11:10-12, 15-17, 19-20 CEV`   `2 Chronicles 12:10-12, 15-17, 19-20 FCBH` with the Bible version being a maximum of 5 characters all together ? I really appreciate your effort

Comment: @ManOfGod I won't edit my answer above, mainly because it answers the question using the data actually provided.  In addition, there are probably other edge cases not covered.  But [here is a demo](https://rextester.com/NNER47665) with the additional changes you asked for in the comment above.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir, you have just worked for God by providing this answer. S0 should have a way we can freely give to those who help us fast for things important like this either money or a choice to even sacrifice a rep or something. Thank you so much

Comment: I am something of an expert with Biblical Hebrew (and Qur'anic Arabic too), so when I saw your question, I had some interest.